# JSON cURL - invalid argument for foreach() - PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach

I'm using this code:

```
<?php

$json_url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=royal&wedding';

$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json')
);

curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

$result =  curl_exec($ch);

if (!empty($result)){
    $json = json_decode($result);
    foreach ($json->results[0]->text as $t){
        var_dump($t);
    }
}

?>
```

But i'm getting an invalid argument for the foreach??

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know how json_decode works, but ,at the first glance, it seems you're searching for iterate the text value of the result[0] of your json output. This is wrong. Try to iterate $json results variable and inside the foreach cycle you can read the text value of the current item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var_dump($json->results[0]->text);
```

And you'll get something like:

```
string(166) "RT @womensweard...
```

which means, you're trying to iterate over a string.

I guess, what you want is:

```
foreach ($json->results as $t){
  var_dump($t->text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looping the `text` property of the first result. If you want to output the `text` for each result, you need to loop the results instead:

```
foreach ($json->results as $t){
    var_dump($t->text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the CURL request succeeded:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result === FALSE) {
    die(curl_error($ch));
}
```

Then check that you actually received JSON data:

```
var_dump($result);
```

then check if the json_decode succeeded:

```
$json = json_decode($result);
if(is_null($json)) {
    die(json_last_error());
}
```

Then check if there actually is a 'results' entry in the json data:

```
if (!isset($json->results)) {
   die("No results section");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea: `$result` is not a valid JSON, and your `$result` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Adding CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false to the CURL options within the performRequest() method in TwitterAPIExchange.php seems to solve it.

cf [here](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/issues/32)