# Execute php curl inside foreach looping

Tags: php, curl, foreach, php-curl

I'm trying to get an users data list throught an url with user ID parameter that return just one user data each time, but to get one user data, i need to change the user ID parameter inside url. In this case, i would like to use curl inside a foreach looping to get all data without need to change the user ID parameter each time.

In my php script, i tried to get all users data at once using *while*, but i know that this is not the correct way to do this and during my research here, i found some similiar questions that use *foreach* to execute curl, but unfortunatly i did not find a correct way to solve this:

1. [Using cURL in a foreach-loop (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47623277/using-curl-in-a-foreach-loop-php)
2. [PHP Array cURL foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614656/php-array-curl-foreach)
3. [curl execution inside foreach loop php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665451/curl-execution-inside-foreach-loop-php)
4. [JSON cURL - invalid argument for foreach() - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858667/json-curl-invalid-argument-for-foreach-php)

Below is the php script that i'm trying to get all users data using *while looping* where i put curl inside:

```php
// database connection file
include 'db_connection.php';

// prepared statement query
$stmt = $db -> prepare('SELECT userID FROM users'); 
$stmt -> execute(); 
$stmt -> store_result(); 
$stmt -> bind_result($userID);

//While looping

while($stmt -> fetch()){

// curl to get users data from api url
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.user.com/api/user/'.$userID.'?key=8aaa03390f0842c6",
    
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

echo $response.'<br>';
    
}
```

As showed above, i put curl inside *while looping* but this is not a correct way to do this. In this case, how can i get all data throught url using curl inside php foreach?

Comment: Unless the API has an option for retrieving multiple records at the same time, the loop is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my doubt. As @Barmar mentioned on his comment, i modified my script to get users information from api url using curl inside *while loop* as below:

```php
//database connection
include 'db_connection.php';

$stmt = $db -> prepare('SELECT userID FROM users'); 
$stmt -> execute(); 
$stmt -> store_result(); 
$stmt -> bind_result($userID);

while($stmt -> fetch()){
    
$url = 'https://api.user.com/api/user/'.$userID.'?key=8aaa03390f0842c6';
    
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $resp.'<br><br>====================================================<br><br>';

}
```